# Ripley's K Function and L Function for Point Patterns

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spatial, poisson-process, point-process, ripley-k

The following is a spatial point pattern: [image]

and these are the corresponding Ripley's K function and L function for this data:
[image]

[image]

How are these functions interpreted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If L(observed) < L(expected), the pattern is more regular than expected, if L(observed) > L(expected) the pattern is clustered

Comment: So would this say that at distances of 0.15 or greater, the cells are randomly and evenly dispersed, but at closer distances the cells are organized in a way that avoids clustering -- perhaps implies a kind of repulsion?

Comment: I would use the simulation (envelope()) function before I put any statements on that, you need to evaluate how many times you could observe similar values of L by chance

Comment: A nice(r) graph is to plot r-L vs r (or L-r vs r) so deviations from the expected value under CSR (now=0) are shown as positive or negative. Also, envelopes will be symmetrical(ish) around zero

Comment: But how is this different than the K function? What pros does L function have over K function?